# Parallel.Invoke() without waiting on execution to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Please know that I'm aware that Parallel.Invoke() is meant for task synchronization. My question is this:

Is there a way to call an anonymous method using something like Parallel.Invoke in which the call does NOT wait on the execution to finish?

I thought the whole point of parallel execution (or parallel invokation) is to NOT have to wait for the task to finish. If you want to wait for a piece of code to finish executing, instead of using Parallel.Invoke, why not just call the code directly? I guess I just don't understand the point of Parallel.Invoke. The documentation just says *what* it does, but doesn't mention any use-cases when this would be more useful than just calling the code directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> If you want to wait for a piece of code to finish executing, instead of using Parallel.Invoke, why not just call the code directly?

Well normally you'd call `Parallel.Invoke` with multiple pieces of work. If you execute those pieces of work in series, it'll (probably) take longer than executing them in parallel.

"Execute in parallel" isn't the same as "execute in the background" - you appear to be looking for the latter, but that's not what `Parallel.Invoke` is about.

If you just want to start tasks, use `Task.Run` (or `Task.Factory.StartNew` prior to .NET 4.5). `Parallel.Invoke` is specifically for executing a bunch of actions *in parallel*, but then waiting for those parallel actions to complete.

As a concrete example, you can perform a sort by partitioning, then recursively sorting both sides of the pivot in parallel. Doing this will make use of multiple cores, but you would usually still want to wait until that whole sort had completed before you proceed.

Comment: You're right, I was under the impression that executing in parallel is the same as executing in background. Can you tell me what the difference is and how it applies to Parallel.Invoke? Or point me to a resource that can help me understand the difference?

Comment: @Anshul: Executing in parallel is simply using multiple cores to accomplish a goal. That *can* be done in a "fire and forget" way, but it's not always. See my edit for a concrete example of when it's useful to parallelize work without making it a background task.

Comment: If I have 2 Parallel.Invokes in sequeunce, wouldn't the 2nd one wait until the first one is finished to be called? In that case, how would you execute the multiple pieces of code in parallel using Parallel.Invoke?

Comment: @Anshul `Parallel.Invoke(action1,action2);` both actions will run in parallel  but *Parallel.Invoke* will wait both of them to finish. Suppose their execution times are `t1` and `t2`. `Parallel.Invoke` will wait `max(t1,t2)`seconds.

Comment: @L.B That makes sense now. I just had the wrong idea in my head about what Parallel.Invoke is *supposed* to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Task.Run is essentially what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Hey @JonSkeet, is there a way to execute code when the last parallel task has finished ? Right now i have several `async () => await Foo();` in the Parallel.Invoke, and I can't seem to find the sweet spot. It either takes the additive complete time of each consecutive call, or less than a second and clearly skips the waiting.

Comment: @Zil: It sounds like you should ask a new question. It's slightly unusual (IMO) to use `Parallel.Invoke` *and* async/await at the same time...

Comment: You're right. I'm confused, i'll write a specific question :)

Answer (score 7):

Simply wrap your `Parallel.Invoke` call in a `Task` if you don't want to wait for completion.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        Parallel.Invoke( <one or more actions> );
    } );
```

Comment: What if I was to do Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{//do whatever}); instead of using Parallel.Invoke? Wouldn't it have the same effect since you're starting a new task essentially?

Comment: Sure, you would need to start a new task for each action you wish to execute in parallel, though.

Comment: Understood. Seems like I was misunderstanding the reason behind Parallel.Invoke().

Comment: If you're simply looking to execute an action on a background thread, create a task for that action.  `Parallel.Invoke` is if you want to execute multiple actions 'simultaneously'

Comment: and then synchronize after their execution completes

Comment: Best not to use StartNew use Task.Run!  I see this mistake all the time.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
async Task ParallelInvokeAsync(Action[] actions)
{
    var tasks = actions.Select(a => Task.Run(a));
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Background execution:

```
ParallelInvokeAsync(actions); 
MessageBox.Show("I'm working");
```

Background execution with blocking, very similar to `Parallel.Invoke`:

```
ParallelInvokeAsync(actions).Wait(); 
MessageBox.Show("I'm dome working");
```

Comment: I suppose that would work as well. I just needed something that makes use of the TPL and executes a piece of code *in parallel with the current line of execution*. By that I mean that the current line of execution should not wait on the parallelized task to finish. Task.Factor.StartNew(()=>{}) satisfies this requirement. I wanted to keep the call succint mainly.

Comment: @Anshul, how you use it depends on the caller. I updated the answer to illustrate it. Theoretically, `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.Invoke(actions))` would create one more thread than the `ParallelInvokeAsync(actions)` above.